# unable to login phpMyAdmin using WAMP

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, wamp

I'm learning to work with WordPress and for this i have installed WAMP server on my system(i am working on Windows). everything seems good. localhost is running but while trying to login in phpMyAdmin i am getting this error
[#1045 - Access denied for user 'ashish'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePqNz.png)

Now this question has been asked here quite a few times but the solutions doesn't seem to work for me.

- I've tried to edit my config.inc file to set username and password as i want
- I'm not running Skype as well
- one important thing i want to mention is, I have installed WAMP server for the second time this time. I had the older one uninstalled from control panel(i am running windows).

Please guide me to solve this problem 
thanks.

Comment: Do you have a user called ashish for your database? Have you tried another user, like root?

Comment: I remember checking your ports and reallocate your ports. If there used, kill them or change them even though Skype is closed.

Comment: no, i haven't done anything apart from installing WAMP and opening phpMYAdmin. do i need to create the database first ? what's with using root if i have specified the user name ashish in config file?

Comment: MySQL probably doesn't have the user you're trying to log in with. Try using root as a user and no password.

Comment: i've checked the listening ports. port 80 is free.

Comment: that did it! can you please explain the science behind it?

Comment: I'll leave an answer.

Comment: if jurgemaister provided you the answer to your problem. I guess you skipped the installation process too quickly to know the "how to".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install WAMP, it comes with a standard install of MySQL. The standard user for MySQL is `root` and there is no password.

Before you can add your own user `ashish`, you need to log in as root and add this user (or just use root if it's for testing only).